# Pandas Drop Duplicates Series Hashing Error

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a pandas dataframe but when dropping duplicate rows I am given the error:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

This happens when I run:

```
print(type(data)) # <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> check that it's not a series
data.drop_duplicates(subset=['statement'], inplace=True)
print(data.info())
```

Info returns this:

```
> class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
> Int64Index: 39671 entries, 0 to 39670
> Data columns (total 4 columns):
> statement          39671 non-null object
> topic_direction    39671 non-null object
> topic              39671 non-null object
> direction          39671 non-null object
> dtypes: object(4)
> memory usage: 1.5+ MB
> None
```

Comment: What does you data look like.  Print info() and show head().

Comment: Looks like `data['statement']` is a Series of series. Is it? What does `type(data['statement'])` report?

Comment: @ScottBoston I added the info

Comment: @DYZ type(data.statement) returns <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Series cannot be used for duplicate elimination because it is mutable. You must convert it into something immutable (`frozenset`, `tuple`, `string`?)

Comment: @DYZ Yeah, looks like that was the issue I found the error, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the individual elements in your `'statement'` column are `pandas.Series`.  That is a clear sign that things have gone astray.  You can validate my claim by running  `data['statement'].apply(type)` you should see a bunch of `<pandas.Series>` or something similar.

If you're stuck with the situation, try

```
df[~df['statement'].apply(tuple).duplicated()]
```

This forces each element of the `'statement'` column to be a `tuple` which **is** hashable.  Then you can find the duplicate rows and filter.

Comment: Looks like this is the situation, I found the line that was doing this. Thank you I will accept once time is up.

Comment: Wow, @piRSquared.  Is this something you've run accross before?  Great insight.

Comment: Yes.  But the biggest clue is the error message.  `'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`.  In order to determine duplicity, you have to be able to hash.  `Series` objects are not hashable like the messages says.  tuples generally are and therefore are a good target class to run the same logic.